# jQuery time function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, setinterval

Hello I have this snippet of jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get("<?echo $site['url'];?>modules/tuitting/tuitting_core/classes/count.php", function (data) {
        var resultDiv = document.getElementById('count');
        resultDiv.innerHTML = data;
    });
});
```

Now what I need is to make this function continuosly checking the data, even when the page is not refreshing. I think I should use a jquery timing function, but I do not really know jQuery at all, and I am lost. Who is so nice to provide the code to me? That would be VERY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: click on the link in the 1st comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put it in a function with `setTimeout`:

```
function repeat_get()
{
  $.get("<?echo $site['url'];?>modules/tuitting/tuitting_core/classes/count.php", function (data)
  {

    var resultDiv = document.getElementById('count');

    resultDiv.innerHTML = data;
    setTimeout(repeat_get, 2000); //2 seconds
  });
}
```

Comment: what happens if the server takes longer than 2 seconds to respond?

Comment: @jnpcl, its not a setInterval, so it wont have compounding issues like the other answers do (as i think you are implying)

Comment: @jnpcl: that's not a problem with @Neal's answer. It _is_ a problem with @Mark's and @Tejs' answers.

Comment: @Matt: I was going to comment on the `setInterval` answers, but I figured it would be better to have information tied to the correct answer. ;)

Comment: @Neal: To me, "this is the proper method because..." is better than "this is the wrong method because..."

Comment: @Neal: No, but you did.. which was exactly my plan. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is put this on an interval:

```
setInterval(function()
{
     $.get("<?echo $site['url'];?>modules/tuitting/tuitting_core/classes/count.php", function (data) 
     {
         var resultDiv = document.getElementById('count');
         resultDiv.innerHTML = data;
     });
}, 2000);
```

This will invoke the callback defined every 2000 milliseconds. In your read event, you simply start the interval:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     setInterval(...);
});
```

Comment: those can compound on top of each other if the get takes longer than your set time!!